# need to pass api response cookie captured under request has to be passed to next api using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We have one api `/user/self` which would recognize the user on the browser if the user has logged in the browser already and shows the result by reading the `cookie` value.

How can it be achieved in `JMeter`. There is one API for login which gives `cookie` data in request after running the request. Basically have to fetch that cookie data and pass it to the next API.loginapi-requestwith cookies[image: /self request and response details]
[image: /login api with cookie request]
[image: /self response]
Adding image of http header manager[image: Adding image of http header manager]
Please help to achieve this using `JMeter`.

Answer (score 3):

JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) can store the cookies as JMeter Variables, all you need to do is add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

and restart JMeter to pick the property up. After that JMeter will store the cookies values as JMeter Variables prefixed by `COOKIE_`, so if you need to re-use the value of the cookie named `FOO` somewhere in your script you can just refer to it as `${COOKIE_FOO}`

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Tried as suggested but didn't work. Added a line CookieManager.save.cookies=true in user.properties file, added debug sampler. In debug sampler able to get values. Login api (Put method) response shows Cookie Data:
connect.tnfsid=s%3Atd0vIKe0lJ4Vc; AWSELB=EB27495B1A64D015A0E02B226FD0E1F21 also added http cookie manager at test plan level. Please suggest what other things can be done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you can now refer cookies values as `${COOKIE_connect.tnfsid}` and `${COOKIE_AWSELB}` correspondingly. Also given you are testing a load-balanced web application make sure you add [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) to your Test Plan

Comment: /self api doesn't have any parameters to be passed, it has to pick the cookie from previous request and pass to itself get user details. I have defined these cookie values under Http cookie managers for this api request, but no use. Not able to get cookie, getting no cookie in /self api request.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

1. Add [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for Login Request
2. Add one more HTTP Sampler for `/user/self`
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), which handles the Cookies, by default. i.e., If cookies are sent by `Set-Cookie` header by server, then JMeter automatically saves them and send it subsequent requests.

Screenshot reference:

[image]

References:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request
2. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Comment: Tried as suggested but didn't work. Added debug sampler. In debug sampler able to get values. Login api (Put method) "request" shows Cookie Data:
connect.tnfsid=s%3Atd0vIKe0lJ4Vc; AWSELB=EB27495B1A64D015A0E02B226FD0E1F21 also added http cookie manager at test plan level. Please suggest what other things can be done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest adding `Debug Sampler` & `View Results Tree` to check what is the cookie sent by server and what cookie is sent in subsequent requests. Please share the screenshots of View Results Tree showing server-sent cookie and cookie sent in next requests

Comment: DebugSampler response data: JMeterVariables:
COOKIE_AWSELB=EB27495B1A64D015A0EA5D9BE47234FB
COOKIE_connect.tnfsid=s%l26D1m8.ygm96Nkrk   Login API request cookiedata: Cookie Data:
connect.tnfsid=s%l26D1m8.ygm96Nkrk; AWSELB=EB27495B1A64D015A0EA5D9BE47234FB

Comment: That means Cookies are saved by JMeter, now the question is, those cookies sent in subsequent requests? whats your observation? pls add screenshots to the question instead of comment

Comment: Sorry to say..i don't know how to add images in the comment section.. :(

Comment: add it to the question, not to the comments. use `edit` link which is available under the question. there you can add images.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Added images.

Comment: ok. thanks. Is the domain name for `login request` & `/user/self` same? any sub-domain in place for the later request? If yes, please change the settings in `jmeter.properties` file as follows: `CookieManager.check.cookies=false`. `Restart JMeter`and run the script.

Comment: Thanks for the info again. both REST apis are in the same domain, only the path is different at the end. i have tried by making false (CookieManager.check.cookies=false), no luck. :(

Comment: Would like to add some more info. In the browser, when accessed the login url and logged in with valid user, in another tab pasted the same /user/self api it shows the details of the user (by reading the cookies). Trying to do the same thing using Jmeter.

Comment: Add `HTTP Header Manager` as a child to `user/self` sampler, and add `Cookie` as name '${COOKIE_connect.tnfsid};${COOKIE_AWSELB}' as value and try

Comment: Added as suggested, no luck yet.. :(. There is one more REST API which is able to get the cookies from login API.